# MySQL form on MAMP not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mamp

The problem is I simply want to insert the fullname/address. I created a users table with the following columns: id (primary), fullname (unique), address (unique).

Here's the code:

```
<?php $username = "root";
$password = "artislife23";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("test",$dbhandle) 
or die("Could not select examples");?>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<h1><?php if(($selected!=null)){
echo "Database is on lock.";}
if(($dbhandle!=null)){
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
}?></h1>
<form method="post" action="input.php">
<tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="fullname" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address</td><td><input type="text" name="address" size="40"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
```

Here's input.php

```
<?php
$postr="INSERT INTO users 
(fullname, address) VALUES('$_POST[fullname]','$_POST[address]')";
$result = mysql_query($postr);
echo "$result";?>
```

All that I can see that's happening is a single blank entry was inserted into the table. Am I doing something wrong here? All I want is to successfully insert the form data into my users table here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST['fullname']
```

you are missing quotes in your POSTs.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work is that PHP doesn't expand arrays in strings the same way it does variables without some weird syntax I can never remember. Change:

```
$postr="INSERT INTO users (fullname, address) VALUES('$_POST[fullname]','$_POST[address]')";
```

To:

```
$postr="INSERT INTO users (fullname, address) VALUES('".$_POST['fullname']."','".$_POST['address']."')";
```

You were also missing the quotes on the array keys.

Additional notes:

1. Your code is ***wide open*** to SQL injection, if I entered my name as `Bobby'; DROP TABLE users;--` guess what would happen?
2. `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated, take the time to learn PDO or MySQLi. They have neat thigns called 'parameterized queries' that allow you to easily avoid SQL injection like I've noted above.
3. Assuming that either a person's full name or address to be unique to them is a design mistake, don't do this in a 'real-world' project.

#### Edit

Alternate syntax for embedding arrays in strings:

```
$string = "Fee fie {$foo['bar']}.";
```

Comment: Awesome response! Thank you. I'm a front end designer making my way to the database side of design. So all that was extremely helpful.

Comment: Also you say addressing them as unique is a design mistake, what would be the right the way to do it?

Comment: @AndrewSquire shocking amounts of people have the same first, last, and even middle initials/names, which is why it's not recommended to use that as a primary key. Ideally you would either want to use something that is guaranteed unique per-person like a user-chosen username or email address, or choose a combination of fields to create a unique composite key.

Comment: Oh, right. I have an ID column that I use as the primary key. A good comparison I saw on the subject of mysql is that primary keys should work just like social security numbers - which backs up what you're saying too. I decided I'm just going to pursue learning PDO.

Comment: @AndrewSquire yep. ID numbers [SSNs, account numbers, etc] are called 'surrogate keys' which are unchanging, unique values assigned to individual records to... well generally make life easier. I thought I put that in my previous comment, but I guess I forgot. :I